# How to force word wrapping of UILabel that adjusts font size and is multiline

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel, line-breaks, multiline

The problem I am facing is that `UILabel` will break line in the middle of the word although I am using word wrapping.

You can create a new project and replace content of view controller to see the result:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    label.numberOfLines = 2 // Setting this to 1 produces expected result
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    view.addSubview(label)

    label.text = "Singlewordtext"
    label.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

This produces 2 lines of text which is broken in the middle of the word. The reason this naturally happens is because the word itself is wider than the label itself so it makes sense (I guess). But I would hope that it would use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumScaleFactor` prior to breaking it. If I set it to single line (`label.numberOfLines = 1`) I get expected result which is that the text will shrink instead of break. Note that doing so in this case will fit all of the text inside the label.

The question is, is there a configuration on `UILabel` to prevent line break in such case? Or is there some other elegant solution?

A current result:

[image: Current result]

Desired result (produced by using `label.numberOfLines = 1`):

[image: Desired result]

Do note that I still do need to have 2 lines enabled to nicely display for instance `label.text = "Three words fit"`.

[image: Expected result with 2 lines]