# UILabel Splits Text String onto Multiple Lines

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` with a fixed width and height. I've set a minimum font scale for the autoshrink property and truncate tail as the line break property. The lines property is set to 0. (Appended image below)

My issue is that for some text, the `UILabel`  splits a word across two lines. Is there a way to manage this? For example, for the word "friendship", the `UILabel`  has "friendshi" on one line and on the next, it has "p".

I've tried setting different line break types, but the changes don't resolve the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try changing the line break mode to "word wrap"

Comment: @HangarRash i did try, but it resulted in the same outcome! :(

Comment: If you are using word wrap then the word should not be split into multiple lines. There is an exception to this rule when word itself is too long to fit into a single line. Could you show a screenshot of your result which also highlights the frame of your label with word that is split into multiple lines. Anyway, you might be out of luck if word does not fit the width of the line. What would you even expect as a result in this case?

Comment: @MaticOblak added a photo! i guess my hope was for the label to both shrink its font size if the text was either longer in height or width than the provided label frame and initial font size..

Comment: Yes, this looks like a problem when single word is too long to fit width. Ironically I remembered I have posted a similar question almost 4 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56683776/526828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to implement Font scaling and word-wrapping on a multiline label has been a long-standing task.

The first issue is not directly related to using auto-shrink.

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode) on line-break mode:

> case **byWordWrapping**
>
> The value that indicates wrapping occurs at word boundaries, unless the word doesn’t fit on a single line.

So, a `UILabel` with `system font / bold / 60`, number of lines: `0`, constrained to `w: 300.0, h: 160.0`, we get this:

[image]

If we set auto-shrink with min scale of `0.5`, we get the same thing... because the label is tall enough to wrap onto multiple lines.

If we change the height of the table to `120.0` - so it's only tall enough for a single line - font scaling **will** occur and we get this:

[image]

Now, I'm assuming - since you have number of lines set to Zero and the label is much taller than needed - you're going to have more text than just that single word... but, let's approach a single-word "fix" first.

Some searching finds this article (***not mine***): [Dynamic Text Resizing in Swift](https://medium.com/@joncardasis/dynamic-text-resizing-in-swift-3da55887beb3) which uses a couple `UILabel` extensions to "fit the text to the label." Here is the relevant code - the only modifications are to change the old `NSAttributedStringKey` to `NSAttributedString.Key`:

```
extension UIFont {
    
    /**
     Will return the best font conforming to the descriptor which will fit in the provided bounds.
     */
    static func bestFittingFontSize(for text: String, in bounds: CGRect, fontDescriptor: UIFontDescriptor, additionalAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil) -> CGFloat {
        let constrainingDimension = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)
        let properBounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size)
        var attributes = additionalAttributes ?? [:]
        
        let infiniteBounds = CGSize(width: CGFloat.infinity, height: CGFloat.infinity)
        var bestFontSize: CGFloat = constrainingDimension
        
        for fontSize in stride(from: bestFontSize, through: 0, by: -1) {
            let newFont = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: fontSize)
            attributes[.font] = newFont
            
            let currentFrame = text.boundingRect(with: infiniteBounds, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: attributes, context: nil)
            
            if properBounds.contains(currentFrame) {
                bestFontSize = fontSize
                break
            }
        }
        return bestFontSize
    }
    
    static func bestFittingFont(for text: String, in bounds: CGRect, fontDescriptor: UIFontDescriptor, additionalAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil) -> UIFont {
        let bestSize = bestFittingFontSize(for: text, in: bounds, fontDescriptor: fontDescriptor, additionalAttributes: additionalAttributes)
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: bestSize)
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    
    /// Will auto resize the contained text to a font size which fits the frames bounds.
    /// Uses the pre-set font to dynamically determine the proper sizing
    func fitTextToBounds() {
        guard let text = text, let currentFont = font else { return }
        
        let bestFittingFont = UIFont.bestFittingFont(for: text, in: bounds, fontDescriptor: currentFont.fontDescriptor, additionalAttributes: basicStringAttributes)
        font = bestFittingFont
    }
    
    private var basicStringAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] {
        var attribs = [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]()
        
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode
        attribs[.paragraphStyle] = paragraphStyle
        
        return attribs
    }
}
```

We then call `label.fitTextToBounds()` (*in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` because the label size needs to be valid*), and the result - again with `system font / bold / 60`, number of lines: `0`, constrained to `w: 300.0, h: 160.0`:

[image]

and we're looking pretty good.

Two issues though...

First, that code is calculating the "best fit" point size for the label bounds, and if we change the text to "friend":

[image]

we end up with a point-size of `111` - which I'm assuming is not your goal.

So, let's make a small modification:

```
extension UILabel {
    
    func fitTextToBounds(maxPointSize: CGFloat) {
        guard let text = text, let currentFont = font else { return }
        
        let bestFittingFont = UIFont.bestFittingFont(for: text, in: bounds, fontDescriptor: currentFont.fontDescriptor, additionalAttributes: basicStringAttributes)

        // keep the font size less-than-or-equal-to max
        let ps: CGFloat = min(maxPointSize, bestFittingFont.pointSize)

        font = UIFont(descriptor: currentFont.fontDescriptor, size: ps)
    }
    
}
```

Now we can call it with `label.fitTextToBounds(maxPointSize: 60.0)` and the result is:

[image]

The second issue is that the extension does not account for multiline labels... If we change the string to "FRIENDSHIP is good." we get:

[image]

So, let's try a little change... we'll split the string into words and find the minimum point size needed so the *longest single word* will fit in the width:

```
extension UILabel {
    
    func multilineFitTextToBounds(maxPointSize: CGFloat) {
        guard let text = text, let currentFont = font else { return }
        
        let a: [String] = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
        var minFS: CGFloat = currentFont.pointSize
        a.forEach { s in
            let bestFittingFont = UIFont.bestFittingFont(for: s, in: bounds, fontDescriptor: currentFont.fontDescriptor, additionalAttributes: basicStringAttributes)
            minFS = min(minFS, bestFittingFont.pointSize)
        }
        minFS = min(minFS, maxPointSize)
        
        font = UIFont(descriptor: currentFont.fontDescriptor, size: minFS)
    }
    
}
```

and we're looking better:

[image]

Unfortunately, if we use this text - "FRIENDSHIP is good for everyone in the world." - the string will exceed the label's height:

[image]

So, let's ***also*** implement auto-shrink:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

label.multilineFitTextToBounds(maxPointSize: 60.0)
```

and...

[image]

Unless I misunderstood your task, or you have additional requirements, that may be a solution.

Here's a quick example controller using the above extensions:

```
class LabelTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 60.0, weight: .bold)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            
        ])
        
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        
        label.text = "FRIENDSHIP is good for everyone in the world."
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        label.multilineFitTextToBounds(maxPointSize: 60.0)
    }
    
}
```